# Find a element in two dimension collection(without var)

Tags: scala

I have a two dimension collection(say `Vector[Vector[Int]]`) and I want to find the index of a element in it. My solution is like:

```
def find(vec: Vector[Vector[Int]], target: Int) = {
  def indexOfTarget(v: Vector[Int]) = v.indexOf(target)

  val r = vec.indexWhere((v) => indexOfTarget(v) != -1)
  val c = indexOfTarget(vec(r))

  (r, c)
}
```

But it's just... ugly. And it invokes `indexOfTarget` one more time than necessary.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
vec.view.zipWithIndex.map {
  case (iv,i) => (i, iv.indexOf(target))
}.find(_._2 != -1)
```

Note that thanks to the `view`, the `zipWithIndex` and `map` are evaluated lazily and this hence does only the calculation that is absolutely required.

Comment: I concur, but maybe it should be mentioned, that `view.zipWithIndex` is evaluated lazily, so this should be - well - efficient enough. Also there is no need for the extra `val idxs` here as the find can be attached to the mapping directly like: `veq.view.zipWithIndex.map { case (sub, idx) => (idx,sub.indexOf(target)) }.find(_._2 != -1)`. 
Also one can use `Seq` instead of `Vector`.

Comment: @michael_s Thanks for comment. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
def find(vec: Vector[Vector[Int]], target: Int) = {
  val zipped = vec.zipWithIndex
  val result = for{
    tup <- zipped
    index <- List(tup._1.indexOf(target))
    if (index != -1)
  } yield (tup._2, index)
  result.headOption
}
```

The result type will be an `Option[(Int,Int)]` with it being `None` if no match.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation that returns `Some((x, y))` if the element is present, and `None` otherwise:

```
def find(vec: Vector[Vector[Int]], target: Int) = (for {
  (xs, posX) <- vec.view.zipWithIndex
  (`target`, posY)  <- xs.view.zipWithIndex
} yield (posX, posY) ).headOption


scala> find(Vector(Vector(1, 2, 4), Vector(2, 2, 3)), 3)
res0: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1,2))
```